# Splash Screen Background Image color inconsistent

Tags: android, splash-screen

I have a Splash Screen with a background Image on top of it. I have a Video View which plays the video. The background of the video and that of the rest of the screen must match, hence I extracted the background color from the video and added a background image of the same color in the XML file.

The problem is, the color of the image does not match with the video on all versions of Android.

On Sony Xperia SP with v4.3:
[image: Sony Screenshot]

On Micromax A1 with v6.0.1:
[image: Micromax Screenshot]

How do I get consistent result across all (or most) versions of Android?

XML of Splash Screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/logoback"
    >
    <VideoView android:id="@+id/myvideo"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: On Bluestacks with v4.4.2:-http://i.stack.imgur.com/6QIom.png

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using drawable for setting the background, extract the colour code and set the colour code to background. It might resolve the issue.

Comment: Still gives me same output.Is it the problem due to different android versions?Do different phones render color in different ways?

Comment: I tried it on three devices,I got correct result (backgrounds match) on Bluestacks Emulator with v4.4.2, On Micromax A1 with v6.0.1 background color was close to that of video but not exact ,while on Xperia SP with v4.3 they do not match at all,background looks like white color.

Comment: It shouldn't happen ideally. Try with some other colour codes might be a darker one and check on various devices.